# Invisible cursor in Gtk2 application when ran without Window Manager

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#, xorg

I am starting off a Gtk# application intended to create a GUI configurator tool on my ArchLinux live CD.

I have all the prerequisites for the app baked into the live CD, but I am stumbling on a problem, where, if I start my app without running a window manager - it will have an invisible cursor icon. I can move the mouse around, see the hover effects on buttons, click them - just that there is invisible cursor.

The application is very simply, as I am just starting out:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace StoneInstallerWizard
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            // Initialize GTK.
            Application.Init();

            // Create a window.
            Window window = new Window("StoneInstallerWizard");

            // Attach closing part to the delete event.
            window.DeleteEvent += delegate
            {
                Application.Quit();
            };

            // Window settings.
            window.WindowPosition = WindowPosition.Center;
            window.Resizable = false;
            window.TypeHint = Gdk.WindowTypeHint.Dialog;

            // HorizontalBox.
            var hbox = new HBox();
            window.Add(hbox);

            // Close button.
            var closeBtn = new Button(Stock.Close);
            closeBtn.Clicked += delegate
            {
                Application.Quit();
            };
            hbox.Add(closeBtn);

            // Next button.
            var nextBtn = new Button(Stock.Apply);
            nextBtn.Clicked += delegate
            {
                var message = new MessageDialog(window, DialogFlags.Modal | DialogFlags.DestroyWithParent, MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Ok, "And so we continue...");

                ResponseType messageResponse = (ResponseType) message.Run();

                // Clicked or closed, doesn't matter.
                if (messageResponse == ResponseType.Ok || messageResponse == ResponseType.DeleteEvent)
                {
                    message.Destroy();
                    Application.Quit();
                }
            };
            hbox.Add(nextBtn);

            // Show the window and start the app.
            window.ShowAll();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

If I am to create a defaults-derived `~/.xinitrc` and replace the exec part with my application and continue with `startx` - thats when it boots up, but the cursor is hidden.

Now, if I use the default `xinitrc` configuration (on Arch it comes with twm, three xterms and xclock) and run the app through there, I will have a visible cursor taking up the default style.

If I am to run cinnamon-session, I see my cursor and (I didn't run the app) I assume that the cursor would persist over to the application.

Arch comes with a default Gtk2 configuration file that uses the `Adwaita` theme, which I have also installed.

I assumed that I have to set up a cursor for my Gtk app, so I did try to add `window.GdkWindow.Cursor = new Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.Arrow);`, but apparently that ended up in both (WM and standalone) with NullExceptionError as the GdkWindow variable was not set.

What could be the problem with my cursor disappearing in a stripped X setup?

P.S. All of the configuration files not mentioned are to their defaults.

#### Update

If I add a `TextView` to my application, run it and hover over the `TextView` it will display the text cursor icon `I` and if I hover out, it will revert to the default `X` cross icon, but persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding out that in a `TextView` the cursor becomes visible, I was assured that the problem relies somewhere inside my code.

The issue that `window.GdkWindow` was nullified made me think, that maybe it is not set until the application has been `Run()`.

Somewhere in my memory, popped up a question that I had found on SO about events, that are called once a `Widget` is exposed - started looking for them.

At first, I went with `window.Shown` event:

```
window.Shown += delegate
{
    window.GdkWindow.Cursor = new Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.Arrow);
};
```

Voila! — cursor visible.

Then I went on to switch to the more reasonable `window.Realized` event which also proved worthy.

That's the mistery solved!